# C# WINWORD.exe won't exit - Sort Directory Files assending

Tags: c#, cmd, com

I'm not so expert on C# but i tried to do my best ,
this is a small console application that should get 2 arg2 ( by passing args to the exe or by console input)  i have 2 issue with it and i can't find any other solution

1. Merging the files is not in the correct order, if the files name has
   letters included. ex.
   (1.docx , 2.docx , 3.docx ) it work => result.docx(1,2,3)
   (1test.docx , 2rice.docx , 3john.docx ) => result.docx(3,1,2)
2. Can't get WINWORD.exe to close after its the appliaction is
   completed

> PS: This exe is being called by PHP line CMD.EXE

i tried all possible commands to release com objects then close application ,
what is my mistake here? how to optimize the code correctly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace DocEngine
{
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Value;


        // Note we need to give a default constructor when override it
        public Parameter()
        {

        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void MergeDocuments(string fileName, List<string> documentFiles)
        {

            _Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            _Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();
            Selection oSelection = oWord.Selection;            

            foreach (string documentFile in documentFiles)
            {
                _Document oCurrentDocument = oWord.Documents.Add(documentFile);
                CopyPageSetup(oCurrentDocument.PageSetup, oDoc.Sections.Last.PageSetup);
                oCurrentDocument.Range().Copy();
                oSelection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
                if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(documentFile, documentFiles.Last()))
                    oSelection.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
            }

            oDoc.SaveAs(fileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
            oDoc.Close();                      

            //TODO: release objects, close word application
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSelection);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oDoc);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWord);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oSelection);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oDoc);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWord);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWord);


                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSelection);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oDoc);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWord);
                oSelection = null;
                oDoc = null;
                oWord = null;

                // A good idea depending on who you talk to...
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();


        }


        public static void CopyPageSetup(PageSetup source, PageSetup target)
        {
            target.PaperSize = source.PaperSize;

            //target.Orientation = source.Orientation; //not working in word 2003, so here is another way
            if (!source.Orientation.Equals(target.Orientation))
                target.TogglePortrait();

            target.TopMargin = source.TopMargin;
            target.BottomMargin = source.BottomMargin;
            target.RightMargin = source.RightMargin;
            target.LeftMargin = source.LeftMargin;
            target.FooterDistance = source.FooterDistance;
            target.HeaderDistance = source.HeaderDistance;
            target.LayoutMode = source.LayoutMode;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Path:");
                Parameter parameter1 = new Parameter
                {
                    Name = "dir",
                    Value = Console.ReadLine()
                };

                Console.WriteLine("FileName without ext:");
                Parameter parameter2 = new Parameter
                {
                    Name = "fileName",
                    Value = Console.ReadLine()
                };
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you! ");

                Console.WriteLine("Test parameter1: [{0}] = [{1}]", parameter1.Name, parameter1.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Test parameter2: [{0}] = [{1}]", parameter2.Name, parameter2.Value);

                try
                {

                    List<string> result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(parameter1.Value, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Union(Directory.EnumerateFiles(parameter1.Value, "*.docx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToList();
                    var filename = Path.Combine(parameter1.Value, parameter2.Value);

                    MergeDocuments(filename, result);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
                }
                catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
                }
            }

           else
            {

                //args = new string[2];

                string sourceDirectory = args[0];
                string filename1 = args[1];

                try
                {
                    List<string> result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Union(Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.docx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToList();
                    var filename = Path.Combine(sourceDirectory, filename1);

                    MergeDocuments(filename, result);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
                }
                catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make any of those COM calls or explicit GC calls, and you don't need to explicitly set things to null. You just need to call [`Application.Quit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.quit.aspx).

Comment: I would suggest reducing your problem and reconstructing it piece by piece. Start first with an application that just does `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();` followed by `oWord.Quit();`. Verify that it terminates. Then add in the `oWord.Documents.Add()` and `oDoc.Close()`. Verify that it terminates. Repeat until you find whatever you're doing that causes it not to terminate.

Comment: i tried this   ((_Application)oWord).Quit();  and it worked,i also commented out all the marshal call and GC calls, Thanks alot

Comment: Files are not sorted because Directory.EnumerateFiles doesn't guarantee sorted files -- it enumerates the files in the order that the OS/file system provide them (unsorted). You can sort those easily enough.

Comment: I don't know about the rest of your logic. I can guarantee that removing the Marshal and GC calls would not cause the behavior you just reported. That's another issue for another question.

Comment: Fixed it all , Thanks a lot for help